# How to fetch input from the csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv (input.csv) file as shown below:

```
VM IP Naa_Dev Datastore
vm1 xx.xx.xx.x1 naa.ab1234 ds1
vm2 xx.xx.xx.x2 naa.ac1234 ds1
vm3 xx.xx.xx.x3 naa.ad1234 ds2
```

I want to use this `csv` file as an input file for my python script. Here in this file, first line i.e. (`VM IP Naa_Dev Datastore`) is the column heading and each value is separated by space.

So my question is how we can use this `csv` file for input values in python so if I need to search in python script that what is the value of `vm1` IP then it should pickup `xx.xx.xx.x1` or same way if I am looking for `VM` which has `naa.ac1234` `Naa_Dev` should take `vm2`.

I am using `Python version 2.7.8`

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can look into `Pandas`

Comment: Did you even Google? https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with tabular data like this, the best way is using pandas.

Something like:

```
import pandas
dataframe = pandas.read_csv('csv_file.csv')

# finding IP by vm
print(dataframe[dataframe.VM == 'vm1'].IP)
# OUTPUT: xx.xx.xx.x1

# or find by Naa_Dev
print(dataframe[dataframe.Naa_Dev == 'xx.xx.xx.x2'].VM)
# OUTPUT: vm2
```

Comment: Thanks, this exactly matches to my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

For importing csv into python you can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), in your case the code would look like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep=' ')
```

and for locating certain rows in created dataframe you can multiple options (that you can easily find in pandas or just by googling 'filter data python'), for example:

```
df['VM'].where(df['Naa_Dev'] == 'naa.ac1234')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) module to read the file into a [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame). There is ***a lot*** of parameters for reading csv files with [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv). The [dataframe.to_string()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) function is extremely useful.

Solution: 
    # import module with alias 'pd'
    import pandas as pd

```
# Open the CSV file, delimiter is set to white space, and then
# we specify the column names.
dframe = pd.read_csv("file.csv",
                     delimiter=" ",
                     names=["VM", "IP", "Naa_Dev", "Datastore"])
# print will output the table
print(dframe)

# to_string will allow you to align and adjust content
# e.g justify = left to align columns to the left.
print(dframe.to_string(justify="left"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is probably the best answer but you can also:

```
import csv
your_list = []
with open('dummy.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        your_list += [row]
print(your_list)
```